# Lifetimes and IntoIter in Rust

Tags: rust, treesitter

I was working on some rust utilities for the [rust tree sitter bindings](https://docs.rs/tree-sitter/latest/tree_sitter/). Tree sitter essentially parses some code and creates an abstract syntax [`Tree`](https://docs.rs/tree-sitter/latest/tree_sitter/struct.Tree.html). This tree consists of [`Node`](https://docs.rs/tree-sitter/latest/tree_sitter/struct.Node.html)s representing structures of code (e.g. csharp `class`es) and can be traversed using a [`TreeCursor`](https://docs.rs/tree-sitter/latest/tree_sitter/struct.TreeCursor.html)

I wanted to extend the existing functionality by implementing some wrapper types which I called `ExtendedTree`, `ExtendedTreeCursor` and `ExtendedNode`.

One of the convenience functions I wanted to try and implement, was that I could access the `source`-code which was used for creating the `Extended`-classes from all of the classes. This source code should not change throughout the apllication runtime and I stored it as a `source: Rc<&str>`. Since it is a reference it required a lifetime, which I called `'s`.

Additionally, `TreeCursor` and `Node` have a lifetime, which I called `'t`. The `Tree` does not need a lifetime, so `ExtendedTree` also only has lifetime `'s` and no `'t`.

I wanted to implement a way to create an `ExtendedCursor` from a `&'t ExtendedTree`, which I managed to do:

```rust
fn get_cursor<'t>(self: &'t Self) -> ExtendedTreeCursor<'t, 's>
where
    's: 't,
{
    ExtendedTreeCursor::new(
        self.ts_tree.root_node().walk(),
        &self.get_complete_source().clone(),
    )
}
```

But then I remembered, that there is a `IntoIterator` trait, which should be more elegant.

I did not manage to implement `IntoIterator` though. My best attempt is:

```rust
impl<'t, 's> IntoIterator for ExtendedTree<'s>
where
    's: 't,
{
    type Item = ExtendedNode<'t, 's>;
    type IntoIter = ExtendedTreeCursor<'t, 's>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        ExtendedTreeCursor::new(
            self.ts_tree.root_node().walk(),
            &self.get_complete_source().clone(),
        )
    }
}
```

It causes the following error:

```
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'t` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src\tree_extensions\extended_tree.rs:47:6
   |
47 | impl<'t, 's> IntoIterator for ExtendedTree<'s>
   |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter.
```

Note: removing `'t` causes `undeclared lifetime`s for `type Item` below.

I wonder what I am doing wrong and if it is even possible to implement `IntoIterator` with the lifetimes `'t` and `'s`.

Note: I did manage to implement `Iterator for ExtendedTreeCursor<'t, 's>`.

You can find my complete code [here](https://github.com/daniu54/csharp-tree-sitter-utils-rs/tree/can-not-implement-into-iter/src), or specifically:

- a test for the expected behaviour [here](https://github.com/daniu54/csharp-tree-sitter-utils-rs/blob/can-not-implement-into-iter/src/tree_extensions/extended_tree.rs#L91-L99)

Comment: `Rc<&str>` is probably not what you want. It could be `Rc<str>` or `&str`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you actually want to implement `IntoIterator` for `&'t ExtendedTree<'s>` (a reference to extended tree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the lifetime in the in the trait impl as kmdreko suggested:

```rust
impl<'t, 's> IntoIterator for &'t ExtendedTree<'s>
                              ^^^
```

I overlooked that the `Self` in the `fn into_iter(self)` is actually a reference.

I have also changed the type of `source` to a more manageable `String` as
Chayim Friedman suggested